Trouble running package EKHAD from A=B
The EKHAD package from the book A=B contains many effective algorithms. I want to use one of them in Maple, but I have troubles with the command read.
I saved the file from this link and followed the instructions at the beggining:
#######################################################################
## EKHAD: Save this file as EKHAD. To use it, stay in the             #
## same directory, get into Maple (by typing: maple <Enter> )         #
## and then type:  read EKHAD : <Enter>                               #
## Then follow the instructions given there                           #
##                                                                    #
## Written by Doron Zeilberger, Rutgers University ,                  #
##  zeilberg@math.rutgers.edu.                                        # 
#######################################################################

After running the EKHAD file, I got:
 Last update: April 26, 2018, thanks to Daniel G. DuParc

   Previous updates:   Dec. 11, 2015 (adding procedures AZdI, 

    AZcI ); May 30, 2015 (adding procedure TerryTao )


              May 29, 2014 (adding Ekhad )

          Version of July 2003: adapted to Maple 8 and 9 

               Many thanks to Drew Sills

     In the penultimate Version of Feb 25, 1999 a suggestion

     of Frederic Chyzak was used, with considerable 

            speed-up. We thank him SO MUCH!


         The penpenultimate version, Feb. 1997,

  corrected a subtle bug discovered by Helmut Prodinger


       Previous versions benefited from comments by Paula Cohen, 

             Lyle Ramshaw, and Bob Sulanke.


        This is EKHAD, One of the Maple packages

                 accompanying the book 

                         "A=B" 

      (published by A.K. Peters, Wellesley, 1996) 

  by Marko Petkovsek, Herb Wilf, and Doron Zeilberger.


    The most current version is available on WWW at:

        http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg .

   Information about the book, and how to order it, can be found in

   http://www.central.cis.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html .

 Please report all bugs to: zeilberg@math.rutgers.edu .

        All bugs or other comments used will be acknowledged in future

                       versions.


For general help, and a list of the available functions,

 type "ezra();". For specific help type "ezra(procedure_name)" 




       NULL;

Then I opened new document in same directory as in instructions and typed read EKHAD.mw, but I got the following error:
Error, on line %1, syntax error, character ? unexpected:

^
 Error, while reading `%1`

Here's the screenshot of my situation:
My situation in Maple - screenshot
I am not very experienced in Maple, so I really don't know how to fix the error. I would be really grateful if someone could help me.

You are confused about the worksheet (*.mw) in which the Maple engine runs, and the external text file of Maple commands that are read in to the worksheet, e.g., EKHAD, which I would probably rename EKHAD.txt or EKHAD.mpl. The read command is for reading a file of external commands and is not for opening a worksheet (which is not a text file and is what you are running in your screenshot.).
Both of these should be in the same directory, which you can check with currentdir();.
